# Update all column values in a table with a column value of another table (related by a foreign key)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to populate a new column in a table with data residing in another table's column.

```
    UPDATE  dbo.PackageSessionNodes
    SET     Created_By = 
               (select userid from dbo.PackageSessions, dbo.PackageSessionNodes 
                where  dbo.PackageSessions.PackageSessionId 
                        = dbo.PackageSessionNodes.PackageSessionId)
```

The update fails because of the subquery retuns more than one value.
I'm obviously a sql noob, so any help would be appreciated.

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this syntax:

```
update dbo.PackageSessionNodes set Created_By = p.userid
from dbo.PackageSessionNodes pn
left join dbo.PackageSessions p on p.PackageSessionId = pn.PackageSessionId
```

I assume a PackageSessionNode can only have one PackageSession?

Comment: PackageSessionId is indeed unique for a PackageSessionNode.
That did the trick, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your original query is doing a cartesian join which might explain the multiple results

Replace

```
dbo.PackageSessions , dbo.PackageSessionNodes
```

with

```
  dbo.PackageSessions
```

and add `DISTINCT`

```
UPDATE  dbo.PackageSessionNodes
SET     Created_By = 
           (select DISTINCT userid from dbo.PackageSessions 
          where  dbo.PackageSessions.PackageSessionId = 
             dbo.PackageSessionNodes.PackageSessionId)
```

This will still fail if you have multiple *different* results being returned in which case you need to define which one you want to use.